# how can i show another layout when button pressed?

Tags: android

i have a following code which flip the page but is show same layout  and same activity  i want to change this code when button press its show another screen with diffrent layout how it is possible? source code given below

```
 package com.samir;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.samir.anim.DisplayNextView;
import com.samir.anim.Rotate3dAnimation;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button btnRotateit, btnRotateBack;
RelativeLayout mContainer, relChild1, relChild2;
private boolean isFirstView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
    relChild1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.child1);
    relChild2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.child2);

    btnRotateit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnrotate);
    btnRotateit.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnRotateBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnback);
    btnRotateBack.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnrotate:
        isFirstView = true;
        applyRotation(0, 90);
        break;
    case R.id.btnback:
        isFirstView = false;
        applyRotation(0, -90);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}

private void applyRotation(float start, float end) {
    final float centerX = mContainer.getWidth() / 2.0f;
    final float centerY = mContainer.getHeight() / 2.0f;

    // The animation listener is used to trigger the next animation
    final Rotate3dAnimation rotation = new Rotate3dAnimation(start, end,
            centerX, centerY, 310.0f, true);
    rotation.setDuration(1200);
    rotation.setFillAfter(true);
    rotation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    rotation.setAnimationListener(new DisplayNextView(isFirstView,
            mContainer, relChild1, relChild2));

    mContainer.startAnimation(rotation);

}
     }



  package com.samir.anim;

  import android.view.View;
 import android.view.animation.Animation;
 import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
 import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
 import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

 public class DisplayNextView implements AnimationListener {
RelativeLayout mContainer, relChild1, relChild2;
boolean isFirstView;

public DisplayNextView(boolean isFirstView, RelativeLayout mContainer,
        RelativeLayout relChild1, RelativeLayout relChild2) {
    this.mContainer = mContainer;
    this.relChild1 = relChild1;
    this.relChild2 = relChild2;

    this.isFirstView = isFirstView;
}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    mContainer.post(new SwapViews());
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
}

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
}

public class SwapViews implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        final float centerX = mContainer.getWidth() / 2.0f;
        final float centerY = mContainer.getHeight() / 2.0f;
        Rotate3dAnimation rotation;

        if (isFirstView) {
            rotation = new Rotate3dAnimation(-90, 0, centerX, centerY,
                    310.0f, false);
        } else {
            rotation = new Rotate3dAnimation(90, 0, centerX, centerY,
                    310.0f, false);
        }
        rotation.setDuration(1500);
        rotation.setFillAfter(true);
        rotation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

        mContainer.startAnimation(rotation);

        if (isFirstView) {
            relChild1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            relChild2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            relChild2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            relChild1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }

}

   }




    package com.samir.anim;

 import android.graphics.Camera;
   import android.graphics.Matrix;
  import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;

 public class Rotate3dAnimation extends Animation {
private final float mFromDegrees;
private final float mToDegrees;
private final float mCenterX;
private final float mCenterY;
private final float mDepthZ;
private final boolean mReverse;
private Camera mCamera;

public Rotate3dAnimation(float fromDegrees, float toDegrees, float centerX,
        float centerY, float depthZ, boolean reverse) {
    mFromDegrees = fromDegrees;
    mToDegrees = toDegrees;
    mCenterX = centerX;
    mCenterY = centerY;
    mDepthZ = depthZ;
    mReverse = reverse;
}

@Override
public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth,
        int parentHeight) {
    super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
    mCamera = new Camera();
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    final float fromDegrees = mFromDegrees;
    float degrees = fromDegrees
            + ((mToDegrees - fromDegrees) * interpolatedTime);

    final float centerX = mCenterX;
    final float centerY = mCenterY;
    final Camera camera = mCamera;

    final Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();

    camera.save();
    if (mReverse) {
        camera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, mDepthZ * interpolatedTime);
    } else {
        camera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, mDepthZ * (1.0f - interpolatedTime));
    }
    camera.rotateY(degrees);
    camera.getMatrix(matrix);
    camera.restore();

    matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
    matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
}
        }


       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#DCDCDC"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/child1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnrotate"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btnrotate"
        android:text="@string/rotateit" />
 </RelativeLayout>

 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/child2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnback"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btnback"
        android:text="@string/rotateback" />
     </RelativeLayout>

      </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

use the `setContentView` on your onclicklistener method Like :

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout);
```

**EDIT:** I think you want when `btnRotateit` is press then you want to display `relChild1` and `relChild2` and again press `btnRotateBack` then appear the `mContainer`, Then Try like:

Add the code on the `btnRotateit` onclick Method :

```
relChild1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
relChild2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and Add the code on the `btnRotateBack` onclick Method :

```
relChild1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
relChild2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
mContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Try this one and Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

```
onClick(View v)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.another);
                            ^^^^^^^ 
}
```

**EDIT :**
For example you have two view, you can set visibility `INVISIBLE` or `GONE`

and in onClick apply rotation and change visibility of components

Comment: but how to use diffrent layout value in
ublic DisplayNextView(boolean isFirstView, RelativeLayout mContainer,
        RelativeLayout relChild1, RelativeLayout relChild2) {
function

Comment: i try it code is blast not working bcoz here is 1 parent layout and two child layout how can i use 2 diffrent layout in this code? any idea??

Answer (score 1):

From your response to vishwa, it looks like you don't want to change the layout of your existing activity so much as to change to another activity.  In which chase:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, secondpage.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code

```
 private View view = null ;
 Button addbutton = null;
 ViewGroup parent = null;
 LayoutInflater inflater = null;

 inflater= (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 addbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

 parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.mainxml);


 addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.other, null);
        parent.addView(view);
   }
});
```

Comment: tell me how to set parameter of another layout in
 rotation.setAnimationListener(new DisplayNextView(isFirstView,
            mContainer, relChild1, relChild2));


suppsoe i craete new layout  main2.xml    and another activity secondpage.java   so how i call this page when button presed in mainacitivity???